# How to trigger events using wxperl?

Tags: perl, events, wxwidgets, wxperl

does anybody have a working example for a wxperl-program which starts a second wxperl-program $cmd and sends events to it?
I start $cmd using something like

```
$frame = Wx::Frame->new(undef,-1,'MyName',wxDefaultPosition);
$procID = Wx::NewId();
$proc = Wx::Process->new($frame,$procID);
$pid = Wx::ExecuteCommand($cmd,wxEXEC_ASYNC,$proc));
Wx::Event::EVT_END_PROCESS($frame, $procID, \&reap_child);
```

The last code-line is how my program gets informed about termination of the child-process. This direction of event-triggering is ok - now I'm looking for the other way round:
I'd like to send events from parent to the newly created process: at least "Close", "De-Iconize" and "Focus". How can one do that?

Comment: What windowing system?

Comment: My hope is that wxwidgets/wxperl works on all platforms. In fact, the code should run on Win (XP, 7, 8) and X-Windows (Gtk, KDE).

Comment: But you're not trying to send a Wx message; you're trying to send a message to a process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [wxIPC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_ipc.html) classes for inter-process communications if they're wrapped by wxPerl. You definitely cannot use wx events for this as they work inside a single process only.

Comment: thanks for your hint. My hope was that events will do the job, but this was a vain hope, obviously